# Heroku Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

Tags: heroku, keras

When I deploy my app in heroku there's not any trouble, but when I try to run the app I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

I use pip and I'm working in virtualenv.

```
absl-py==0.7.0 asn1crypto==0.24.0 astor==0.7.1 attrs==18.2.0
backcall==0.1.0 bleach==3.1.0 certifi==2019.3.9 cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4 Click==7.0 cryptography==2.4.2 cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.6 decorator==4.3.0 entrypoints==0.3
fix-yahoo-finance==0.0.22 Flask==1.0.2 Flask-WTF==0.14.2 gast==0.2.2
graphviz==0.10.1 grpcio==1.16.1 h5py==2.9.0 idna==2.8
ipykernel==5.1.0 ipython==7.4.0 ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.4.2 itsdangerous==1.1.0 jedi==0.13.2 Jinja2==2.10
jsonschema==3.0.0a3 jupyter==1.0.0 jupyter-client==5.2.4
jupyter-console==6.0.0 jupyter-contrib-core==0.3.3
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions==0.5.1 jupyter-core==4.4.0
jupyter-highlight-selected-word==0.2.0 jupyter-latex-envs==1.4.6
jupyter-nbextensions-configurator==0.4.1 jupyterlab==0.35.3
jupyterlab-server==0.2.0 Keras==2.1.6 Keras-Applications==1.0.6
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.5 kiwisolver==1.0.1 lxml==4.3.0
Markdown==3.0.1 MarkupSafe==1.1.0 matplotlib==3.0.2 mistune==0.8.4
mkl-fft==1.0.10 mkl-random==1.0.2 multitasking==0.0.7
nbconvert==5.3.1 nbformat==4.4.0 notebook==5.7.4 numpy==1.15.4
pandas==0.23.4 pandas-datareader==0.7.0 pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.3.1 patsy==0.5.1 pexpect==4.6.0 pickleshare==0.7.5
pipenv==2018.11.26 plotly==3.5.0 pmdarima==1.1.0
prometheus-client==0.5.0 prompt-toolkit==2.0.7 protobuf==3.6.1
ptyprocess==0.6.0 pycparser==2.19 Pygments==2.3.1 pyOpenSSL==18.0.0
pyparsing==2.3.1 pyrsistent==0.14.9 PySocks==1.6.8
python-dateutil==2.7.5 pytz==2018.9 PyYAML==3.13 pyzmq==17.1.2
qtconsole==4.4.3 requests==2.21.0 retrying==1.3.3
scikit-learn==0.19.2 scipy==1.1.0 seaborn==0.9.0 Send2Trash==1.5.0
simplejson==3.16.0 six==1.12.0 statsmodels==0.9.0 ta==0.3.8
tensorboard==1.12.2 tensorflow==1.12.0 termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.1 testpath==0.4.2 tornado==5.1.1 traitlets==4.3.2
urllib3==1.24.1 wcwidth==0.1.7 webencodings==0.5.1 Werkzeug==0.14.1
widgetsnbextension==3.4.2 wrapt==1.11.0 WTForms==2.2.1 xgboost==0.81
```

Heroku Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

Comment: I guess your application is written in Python? Please [edit] your question and share your `requirements.txt` (if you're using `pip`) or `Pipfile` (if you're using Pipenv). Paste it directly into your question, then select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to format it as code.

Comment: Kindly see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624007/deploying-node-js-app-that-uses-python-shell-to-heroku   I cannot mark this question as duplicate because the answer has not yet been accepted

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan, that's probably not a duplicate. Nothing in this question references Node.js (or any other programming language), and `ModuleNotFoundError` is a valid Python error. OP's code is probably written in Python (though we don't know for sure since they haven't told us). Once they edit their question to clarify the language and show their dependencies we'll be better able to help.

Comment: Sorry for the format, but I had trouble with “It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.” error.

Comment: @Chris I mentioned that because my guess is OPs making the same error most people do while deploying a node js app with a python shell. They forget to add the python buildpack which results in their required modules not being installed

Comment: @EmilianoAstasio, I've removed a bullet and formatted that block as code. (a) Is that the exact format of your `requirements.txt` file, with multiple things on each line? (b) I see `pipenv==2018.11.26` in that list. Are you using Pipenv?